# Are there any good resources that give a general overview of each day's daf?

Tags: product-recommendation, talmud-gemara, talmud-bavli, daf-yomi

That's not meant to be a substitute for learning it in depth, but rather for review purposes it would be nice to read a brief synopsis. Any tips would be appreciated.

Comment: What language are you looking for. In Hebrew there are many.

Comment: Preferably English

Answer (score 3):

DafDigest is a great resource when learning the daf.

http://www.dafdigest.org/archives.php

Comment: Wow! +1

Answer (score 3):

The [point-by-point outline from dafyomi.co.il](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/berachos/points/br-ps-002.htm) is a good resource.  You can subscribe to it by email, which is how I get it, though I've found the email to be a little erratic in the last year or so.

They also publish a short compilation of background material on each daf along with other [related materials](http://www.dafyomi.co.il/berachos/).

None of this is a substitute for the full text; these are outlines and summaries and, of necessity, incomplete.  For review purposes, though, it looks like it would serve well.  (I'm still mostly learning rather than reviewing, but I've sometimes used it for review.)

Answer (score 1):

http://www.dafyomi.co.il/memdb/revindex.php?fr=kidu
revach l'daf (link goes to kidushin but they have for other tractates as well)

has short summary with brief insight

Answer (score 0):

If you can read form a video
this app [daf hachaim](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.dafhachaim)

Has a very good 1 min and 5 min video of the daf yomi (and also old dafim)

You can probably access it on there website.
http://dafhachaim.org